# Import RRD files into cacti

Tags: rrd, cacti

I have rrd files collected from different hosts. Would like to import rrd files into a cacti instance. I followed what is described here http://docs.cacti.net/manual:087:8_rrdtool.05_external_rrds to generate graphs from RRD files.

How to update files in rra directory without overwriting (append)?